# Origin of crossing relations in relativistic scattering amplitudes

Tags: scattering, s-matrix-theory

What is the origin of crossing relations in relativistic scattering amplitudes?  At first I thought it was CPT, but then it turned out that was not correct.

That is, what is the formal reason that the same function $A(s,t)$ describing the process $A+B\rightarrow C+D$ can also be used to describe the crossed-reaction $A+\overline{C}\rightarrow \overline{B}+D$ provided the role of the invariants $s$ and $t$ are exchanged?

Comment: The creation of a particle of momentum/energy $p$ cannot  be distinguished from the destruction of a antiparticle of  momentum/energy $-p$

Comment: Is this related to the S-T channel symmetry of the Veneziano Amplitude?

Comment: @Dilaton No.  This question is of a more general nature:  why, for example, can the same amplitude function describing electron pair annihilation be used to describe Compton scattering?